# Python3 unexpected visual interaction with input function and CJK

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, osx-elcapitan

Sorry for my poor English, it is not my first language.

I have a Python3 file whose content is just

```
print(input(">"))
```

When I run it on either zsh or bash and write hangul and use my backspace key, unexpected behavior occurs.

If I press "ㄴ" three times, followed up backspace three times, I am left with this:

```
>ㄴ
```

No matter how many times I press backspace, "ㅁ" will not be removed. Similarly, if I initially write "동"

```
>동
```

and then erase it, there is an unremovable whitespace and any other characters I type afterwards looks like

```
> 가나다
```

This seems to be only a visual issue, as if I were to type "ㄴㄴㄴㄴㄴ" and hit backspace until there was no change shown, I would be left with

```
>ㄴㄴ
```

Following, I typed "동" and hit enter.

```
>ㄴㄴ 동
```

would result in

```
동
```

only being printed.

The final oddity with this is that it only occurs when input() is being run from a python file. If I were to do all of this via interactive shell, nothing out of the ordinary happens.

This is occurring on my MBP running El Capitan and it seems to be an issue with all CJK keyboards, I did some minor testing with Chinese and Japanese keyboard and it displayed similar behavior.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Python does absolutely nothing here. It is your terminal emulator application that does the rendering of the characters and the moving of the cursor. In fact, from when it shows the `>` to when you press enter, your python interpreter is completely frozen.

Answer (score -1):

It's behavior of your terminal, print(input(">")) should works